# How do I automatically refresh a GalleryView from a handler called by doInBackground?

Tags: android, handler, galleryview

I am trying to refresh a `GalleryView` with new items by adding the items to the `Adapter` and doing the following inside the handler which is called from inside `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask`.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.arg1 == 1){

            gaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ga.setAdapter(gaAdapter);
            ga.setSelection(midposition);
        }
    }   
};
```

The `GalleryView` seems to respond to the above code but does not automatically refresh itself. The items are updated only when it is horizontally scrolled. How can I do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notifyDataChanged() need to be involved on UI thread, try this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    gaAdapter.add(newListItem);
    gaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    ga.setSelection(midposition);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am going to accept your answer as it is one of the ways of doing it. However, I used Handlers to get the job done. I was just not doing it right the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using
    `ga.invalidate()`